# Using SCP to move a file from windows desktop to a hadoop sandbox on vmware

Tags: unix, hadoop, mapr

I think this is simple but I would really appreciate your help. I have a zip file on my windows desktop "RECEIPTS_LAB.zip" and I am running a hadoop sandbox on vmware. The sandbox is part of a training course I signed up for with mapr but I am a beginner and not sure how to move the zip file from windows to the directory in sandbox which is"/user/user01/3"

The manual uses the following code

***scp RECEIPTS_LAB.zip user01@node-ip:/user/user01/3***

node-ip is the ip address that I got when starting the sandbox, lets assume its 192.168.88.128

When I write the following command:
scp RECEIPTS_LAB.zip user01@192.168.88.128:/user/user01/3

And the error I get is: ***"RECEIPTS_LAB.zip: No such file or directory"***

Please help me understand what should I do since I have tried a lot of times to modify the syntax but I still get the same error

Answer (score 2):

Your error means that you are in the wrong directory.

Have you tried using WinSCP? It will give you an interface that lets you see both your computer directory and the remote computer (in this case the MapR VM) directory.

( https://winscp.net/eng/download.php )

It may make your life easier. Just download the "Portable executables" files from the website and unzip it.

since I am not seeing any port forwarding with your scp command and you are providing an actual IP address I will assume that MapR is running a sandbox with the network adapter in bridge mode.

- Double click the application once it is unzipped to start it.
- Then on the start up screen provide the

  - MapR user for user
  - MapR password for password
  - The IP address of the sandbox for the "host"
  - make sure the protocol is set to SCP in the combo box at the top above where you enter credentials

  You shouldn't have to touch the port number if MapR's tutorial didn't have a -p switch with the scp call.

if the sandbox is at the IP address you gave and you entered the credentials right, WinSCP will load a side by side directory view of your windows machine and the sandbox. from the side by sode screen you can drag and drop between the machines.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to execute `scp RECEIPTS_LAB.zip user01@node-ip:/user/user01/3` from a Windows command prompt. You don't say what version of Windows you are using or which Windows directory you are in when you try to run this command. But as written, it will succeed only if you are in the same directory as the file. If you do not specify a particular directory for the file, Windows looks for it in your current directory. Try this:

1. Press Windows-Key+R to open the "Run" dialog. Enter "cmd" and click "OK".

Now you should be at a command prompt in your Windows home directory -- something like

`C:\Users\Musmar>`

2. Your Desktop folder should be a sub-directory of your home directory -- something like

`C:\Users\Musmar\Desktop`

To verify this, type:

`dir Desktop\RECEIPTS_LAB.zip`

Hopefully you will see a directory listing for your file. Then type:

`scp Desktop\RECEIPTS_LAB.zip user01@192.168.88.128:/user/user01/3`

If my assumptions are correct, that should do what you want or at least get you one step closer.

Comment: I apologize if the information provided was not sufficient. I am using PUTTY and I have Windows 7

Comment: Work through the steps above and see if it works. If it doesn't, post the error message here.

Comment: ok I tried running cmd and everything was exactly as you mentioned above. The dir command verified having the file, but when I tried to execute the scp I got the following error:
'scp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program to batch file

Comment: also i tried running it in putty and got this error:
DesktopRECEIPTS_LAB.zip: No such file or directory

Comment: You're halfway there. Now Windows can't find the path to your scp executable file. If you don't mind taking a little detour, here is a suggestion that will help you in the long run. Try installing WinSCP on your computer. You can download it from here: http://winscp.net/eng/index.php It will be a little extra work now, but once you have that installed, it will be much simpler to use than trying to make Putty scp work from the Windows command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in the Documents of MapR.

ERRORS: Permission denied (publickey,password).

1. First go the the directory where the zip file is present through he terminal.
2. Mention the port through which you need the file to be copied.
3. the port that sandbox allows us is 2222. Default port 22 wont work

**scp -P 2222 RECEIPTS_LAB.zip @:/user/user01/3**

***Again there might be some problem with your scp. so you might uninstall and reinstall the scp client and then try this.